# What are the minimum hardware requirements for .NET nanoFramework?

Tags: firmware, nanoframework, infineon

What are the minimum hardware requirements for .NET nanoFramework?

I want to program an [XMC1404-Q064X0128](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/microcontroller/32-bit-industrial-microcontroller-based-on-arm-cortex-m/32-bit-xmc1000-industrial-microcontroller-arm-cortex-m0/xmc1404-q064x0128-aa/) microcontroller with C# code. It's core is a 48MHz ARM Cortex-M0 with 16KB RAM and 128KB flash memory.

Can .NET nanoFramework run on this chip?

Unless I'm missing something, the biggest concern is maybe not having enough flash memory available. Looking at [Recommended devices to start with .NET nanoFramework](https://docs.nanoframework.net/content/getting-started-guides/where-to-buy-devices.html) the TI_CC1352R1_LAUNCHXL has only 352KB available, but this is nearly 3x more than my XMC1404. I also don't see any [other popular boards contibuted by the community](https://github.com/nanoframework/nf-Community-Targets) with any less than that.

I'm no firmware expert. Is there a simple way to calculate the required flash memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolut minimum requirements, memory wise, it's 192kB of flash and 64kB of RAM.
Now, there is no official port for Infinion MCUs.

Comment: Thanks José. I presume the nanoFramework home page is then slightly outdated. https://www.nanoframework.net/